# How to store data scraped by BeautifulSoup on GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, beautifulsoup, mechanize

My site is able to log in to a 3rd party secured website by using gaemechanize and scrape data by using BeautifulSoup. After log in successfully, if I refresh pages, sometimes, the data will be gone so that "500 Internal Server Error" page will appear; however, sometimes, the data will be stored unexpectedly and those data is shown on other computer without login.
My question is How to store data until user click logout and the only one session can access the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WebApp2 to use Sessions, and store data to that session. Once the user logs out, you can store the data to the datastore permanently or just kill the session and let the data for that session disappear. 
Check out WebApp2 sessions: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html